# Subir busybox a router ftp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, seguridad, ensamblador

Estoy haciendo una prueba en mi router en casa, me gustaría saber si es posible subir el busybox al servidor ftp o telnet que tiene el gateway para así utilizar las opciones de linux.

He buscado documentación en la red pero no encuentro algo en referencia a esto, la mayoría son dirigidos a la apk de Android.

Comment: Para subirlo, ¿a donde te refieres? ¿a tu router de casa? si es así, es imposible responderte sin saber exactamente el modelo de router. Habrá que saber si tiene alguna opción de crear un server ftp o algo similar.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el sistema es *OpenWrt*, se puede realizar siguiendo una serie de pasos.

Para iniciar sesión desde la consola se hace con el siguiente comando:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.1
```

Se puede simplificar sin mencionar el **root**:

```
ssh 192.168.1.1
```

Además, hay que elegir la *ip* del router, no siempre es *1.1*, también, dependiendo de la configuración, puede ser *2.1*, o algún otro.

Luego de esto, se puede instalar `busybox` mediante el comando `opkg`:

```
opkg install busybox
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que la última versión de *Busybox*, perdió algunas características interesantes con respecto a su anterior versión, como por ejemplo, que **sleep no puede usar milisegundos**:

```
busybox sleep 0.1
sleep: invalid number '0.1'
```

Una manera alternativa para obtener *Busybox* desde adentro es instalar `sshfs`:

```
opkg install sshfs
```

Si falla la instalación por las dependencias, se puede usar el parámetro `--force-depends`, esta es una de las maneras para resolverlo:

```
opkg install sshfs --force-depends
```

También, es posible que no se pueda instalar por falta de espacio.

Las dependencias de `sshfs`, pueden ser como estas:

```
ldd /usr/bin/sshfs # sshfs-3.7.2-x86_64-1
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd51d1b000)
    libfuse3.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libfuse3.so.3 (0x00007f54cb386000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f54cb365000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f54cb231000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f54cb051000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f54cb04c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f54cb3c7000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f54cafd4000)
```

Para instalar archivos cuando el router no tiene programas que puedan descargar de internet, como lo es `wget`, se puede convertir los bytes de los archivos a valores hexadecimales, usando el comando `xxd`, estando fuera de *SSH*:

```
xxd -p /usr/bin/sshfs | tr -d '\n' > ./sshfs.txt
```

También, se puede revertir esta operación, convirtiendo esos valores hexadecimales a bytes:

```
xxd -r -p ./sshfs.txt /usr/bin/sshfs
```

Esto puede servir para guardar el archivo desde una terminal que permita pegar texto plano... Para los archivos grandes puede tardar bastante, porque insertar cadenas largas de texto en la consola puede traer problemas con el renderizado.

Entonces, para pegar el texto en la terminal de ventana, como por ejemplo `lxterminal` estando dentro de *SSH*, se hace así:

```
echo 7f454c460201010000... > /usr/bin/sshfs
```

Nota: Los tres puntitos no son reales, esto significa que le siguen miles de caracteres hexadecimales.

Por último, darle los permisos de ejecución al programa ejecutable:

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/sshfs
```

Luego hay que hacer estos mismos pasos con cada dependencia que falte, afortunadamente, este programa no tiene muchas dependencias faltantes, la única es la librería `libfuse3.so.3`.

Primero convertir a hexadecimal:

```
xxd -p /usr/lib64/libfuse3.so.3 | tr -d '\n' > ./libfuse3.so.3.txt
```

Luego haber guardado el texto, como se hizo anteriormente, copiar los valores desde un editor de texto externo y pegarlos en la terminal dentro de *SSH*:

```
echo 7f454c460201010000... > ./usr/lib64/libfuse3.so.3
```

Una vez hecho esto, se pudo forzar la instalación de *SSHFS*... Esto sirve para acceder a las carpetas del ordenador.

Para esto, se vuelve a acceder al router, pero con el parámetro `-R`:

```
ssh 192.168.1.1 -R 10000:localhost:22
```

Ocasionalmente, el *1.1* puede ser otro, como *2.1*, dependiendo de cómo esté configurado.

Luego, el *SSHFS* se usa para montar la carpeta del disco, a la carpeta local:

```
mkdir ./local
sshfs -p 10000 root@127.0.0.1:~/disco ./local
```

En la carpeta `disco` está el *Busybox* antes de ingresarlo al router.

Nota: El nombre de usuario no necesariamente siempre es *root*, para ver la lista de usuarios, puede hacerse lo siguiente.

```
> cat /etc/shadow

root:*:0:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:0:0:99999:7:::
ftp:*:0:0:99999:7:::
network:*:0:0:99999:7:::
nobody:*:0:0:99999:7:::
ntp:x:0:0:99999:7:::
dnsmasq:x:0:0:99999:7:::
logd:x:0:0:99999:7:::
ubus:x:0:0:99999:7:::
```

Con esto, estando dentro del *SSH*, ya se puede copiar el *Busybox* accediendo a los archivos del disco:

```
cp ./local/busybox /usr/bin/busybox
```

La ruta del copiado es a elección personal, puede ser `/bin` o alguna otra que esté en el `$PATH`.

Documentación de *OpenWrt*:

- https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-quick-start/sshadministration
- https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/managing_packages
- https://openwrt.org/faq/cannot_satisfy_dependencies